# Assign (update) CRS for new created from npz file - LAZ file in Python

Tags: python, well-known-text, las

I need to create LAS/LAZ file from npz multidimensional array.
NPZ file contains 3 arrays inside array['wkt', 'data', 'max_min'].

- array['data'] contains list of  X, Y, Z - coordinates that used for creating LAZ - file, but there is no CRS info.
- array['wkt'] - contains info in array format -> |PROJCS["NAD83 UTM 18",GEOGCS["unknown",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26918"]|
- array['max_min'] - offset of borders for X and Y.

Q: How by using Python attached CRS - coordinate referernce  system info - to header(?) of new created LAZ file to be able to see data on specific CRS (from wkt) on the map in QGIS?

I have some code,
[image]

that gives me error: [image]

Some interesting  Link https://laempy.github.io/pyoints/_modules/pyoints/storage/LasHandler.html, but how to use it regarding WKT record from npz file?

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Please always include code and errors as text in the body of the Question. Images are not legible on all devices, need to be retyped to be tested, and can't be searched by others.

Comment: The error is telling you that *geoRecords* isn't defined, where this variable comes from is not inside your sample code block so we really can't help.